# Using SVG instead of raster graphics for web based UI controls/widgets?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have implemented UI controls using JavaScript, CSS and HTML (and SVG). I know that browser support for SVG as background-image is poor, but that does not concern me as the project is not going to launch anytime soon.

However, it feels painful to do things like CSS sprites. It is also a lot more painful to use Illustrator than Photoshop. I am wondering that is the main benefit of vector graphics (scalability) worth this? Do you think it's a good idea to use SVG instead of raster graphics for UI controls like checkboxes, buttons and such?

Comment: Do you need IE and mobile support?

Comment: Firefox 4, IE 9, Opera 11, Safari 5 and Chrome 8.

Comment: Browsers do come with *built in* controls for checkboxes, buttons and such.

Comment: I need more customization, even more than what HTML5 form controls offer like grouping of text fields, paginated drop downs, etc. not to mention a complete new appearence.

Comment: Grouping is handled by `<fieldset>`, pagination of drop downs happens by default, and a complete new appearance means a lot of work to move things away from users' comfort zones.

Comment: By grouping I meant like having two or more text inputs with a maximum length limit, and when pasting text more than the maximum length the rest will continue naturally to the others in the order of tab index. What's that pagination? I have never seen anything like that in drop boxes before, care to share?

Comment: I find it interesting that you find Illustrator more painful.  My experience is the opposite.  Do you just redraw everything in Photoshop when it needs to change size a little?

Comment: Illustrator does not support LAB. The slices are selected with the standard selection tool and are part of the layer list (ugh). Cropping and a plenty of other tools have moved to random places. It looks impossible to color pick a color from a gradient. The color picker works horrible when altering gradients (e.g. doesn't remember the current value). There's no as quick hide-all-layers-except-this as in Photoshop. In overall I think it's very powerful, but I just feel like it's not as well tuned as Photoshop across all these years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's worth it.  Think about people using an app on an iPhone, then using the same app on an iPad—scalability helps a lot.  The most difficult thing is learning the tools necessary to producing the vector graphics.  Illustrator isn't any harder than Photoshop, it's just *different*; you're learning a new paradigm for image editing/creating, as if you're jumping from Java to Haskell.